# Valve logic implementation worked in jboss 6.4 not working in 7.3 jboss

Tags: java, tomcat, jboss7.x, jboss6.x, undertow

Valve not supported in Jboss 7.3 after upgrade from jboss 6.4 and also custom authentication logic added by implementing Catalina.Authenticator class is not supported in jboss 7.3. Has any faced the same? Any solution would be appreciated

I tried same logic with authenticationMechanism class in undertow,but not achieved expected result